# Splitting string

Tags: python, list, split

I have a string "This is my python experience"

I want to split it to "This is", "my", "python", "experience".

How can I split it into first two words as 1 element and then one each ? Is there any reference document ?

Comment: Is split then merge an option?

Comment: what is the basis on which you're trying to split?

Comment: @VishalSingh I want to split the above string to a list with 1st two words as 1st element of list and rest each word as each element of the string.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes anything will work.

Comment: Logic is required. Split always happens on  some separator This might help.

`"This is my python experience"splitstring = [" ".join("This is my python experience".split()[:2])] + "This is my python experience".split()[2:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```
string = "This is my python experience"
splitString = [" ".join(string.split()[:2])] + string.split()[2:]
#output
#['This is', 'my', 'python', 'experience']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
myString = "This is my python experience"
myList = myString.split(" ")
print(myList)
first = myList[0] + " " + myList[1]
second = myList[2]
third = myList[3]
fourth = myList[4]
finalList = [first, second, third, fourth]
print(finalList)
```